# How to make a line break inside a multi-column cell created with the tabularray package?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, multicolumn, tabularray

I made a table using the `tabularray` package. In the first row of this table I want the text to be in two lines, but I can't because I get the error `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end`.

In the [package documentation](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) it says

> just enclose the cell text with braces and use \\ to break lines

, but in this case it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering%
\caption{The table caption}
\label{TAB:example}
\begin{tblr}{%
colspec={%
Q[l,m]%
*{4}{X[si={table-format=2.1},c,m]}%
}}
\cline{2-5}
             & \SetCell[c=4]{c,m}\textbf{Line 1\\Line 2}  &      &     &                \\ \cline{2-5}
             & \textbf{Col 1}        & \textbf{Col 2} & \textbf{Col 3} & \textbf{Col 4} \\ \hline
$\pmb{n}$    & 34                    & 34             & 34             & 34             \\
\textbf{min} & 1,3                   & 1,3            & 1,1            & 1              \\
\textbf{max} & 34,7                  & 38,3           & 25,6           & 15,0           \\ \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The table is not printed due to the error, so I used `\SetCell[c=4]{c,m}\textbf{Line 1$\backslash\backslash$Line 2}` to show you the table.

[image]

Comment: Probably an interaction with the `si=`

Comment: Maybe it's an unusual combination, but `makecell` works here. `\usepackage{makecell}` ... `\SetCell[c=4]{c,m}\textbf{\makecell{Line 1\\Line 2}}`

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Here it didn't work, the error `Undefined control sequence. \end` appeared.

Comment: On the hypothesis that `\textbf` is stalling the desired result, I'd try modifying that cell to be `\bfseries Line 1\\Line 2`,  (Not tested.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `siunitx`, you must indicate or "guard" cells with non-numeric values. Otherwise, you get errors. In `tabularray`, you have to enclose such content in triple braces `{{{...}}}` or add a keyword `guard` in the specification. In other environments, you only enclose non-numeric values in a single braces `{...}`

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{The table caption}
    \label{TAB:example}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={Q[l,m] *{4}{X[si={table-format=2.1},c,m]}},
            row{1,2} = {guard, font=\bfseries},
            column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
            hline{1} = {2-Z}{wd=0.8pt},
            hline{2} = {2-Z}{wd=0.5pt},
            hline{3} = {wd=0.5pt},
            hline{Z} = {wd=0.8pt},
        }
        
                     & \SetCell[c=4]{c,m} {Line 1\\Line 2} & & & \\
                     & Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 \\
        n    & 34     & 34    & 34    & 34 \\
        min & 1,3    & 1,3   & 1,1   & 1 \\
        max & 34,7   & 38,3  & 25,6  & 15,0 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]